# How to add a link in jquery when displaying search results

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, search

I made an ajax search in my project, but I have a problem with adding a link into a jquery code. I can see search results, but I do not know how to get to the page of the result.

my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#q').bind("change input paste", function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    $.get( "/search_suggestions?query="+val, function(data) {
      $('#results').empty();
      $('#results').show();
      $.each(data, function(index, result) {
        $('#results').append('<li>'+result+'</li>');
        $('#results').click(function () {
            //do smth. on click
        });
      });
    });
    //do not display anything
  });
});
```

A view:

```
  <div>
        <%= form_tag('#', method: 'get', id: 'header-search', class: 'navbar-form') do %>
      <div class="input-group">
        <%= text_field_tag(:q, (params[:q].present? ? params[:q] : nil), class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Поиск', autocomplete: 'off') %>
          <i aria-hidden="true" onclick="document.getElementById('header-search').submit();"></i>
          <ul id="results">
            </ul>
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default disabled"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
   <% end %>
  </div>
```

Controller:

```
def search_suggestions
  query = params[:query]
  results = if params[:query].present?
            Doctor.where('name ILIKE ? OR surname ILIKE ?', "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%").select(:surname).collect(&:surname)
          else
            []
          end
  render json: results
end
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
...
 get 'search_suggestions' => 'doctors#search_suggestions', as: :search_suggestions
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: So are you asking what "//do smth. on click" should be?

Comment: Here should be a link to the object found by search

Comment: Can you clarify what an example 'result' would look like?  And what kind of link are you meaning?

Comment: Well, I'm searching a doctor by his name and surname. When I start to print his name or surname, I can see the doctor's surname below the search form. That surname isn't clickable. I want to be redirected to doctor's show action by clicking on his surname